# Sequelize Associantions

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, mariadb, sequelize-js

Possuo 2 models:

user features:

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../config/dbconnection');
const user= require('./user');

const user_features = database.define('user_features', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(6),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(6),
      references: 'USERS',
      referencesKey: 'user_id',
      allowNull: true
    },
    {
      text:{
          type: "LONGBLOB",
          allowNull: true
      }
    },
    {
       timestamps: false
    });

    user_features.belongsTo(user);
    module.exports = user_features;
```

users:

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../config/dbconnection');

const users = database.define('users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(6),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45)
    }
 },
 {
   timestamps: false
 });

 module.exports = users;
```

e no console mostra o seguinte erro:

```
Error: user_features.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

Preciso fazer a associação entre essas tabelas para na regra de negocio eu poder fazer um select no banco de dados e trazer essas informações.

Atualmente eu estou fazendo o select assim:

```
model.sequelize.query('SELECT NAME, TEXT FROM USERS LEFT JOIN USER_FEATURES ON USERS.ID = USER_FEATURES.USER_ID')
```

mas quero padronizar o prejo e queria utilizar o ORM:

```
 getAll = (req, res, next) => model.findByPk(req.params.id,
            {
                attributes: ['NAME', 'TEXT']       
            })
            .then((result) => {
                res.send(result);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('repository getById error: ' + error));
```

Como poderia fazer essa associação?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, se fosse uma classe do tipo Model sequelize vc teria que extender ela pra Model, creio que por isso o Sequelize não está compreendendo que user_features é um model do sequelize. Segue um exemplo da documentação:

```js
sequelize.define('modelName', {
  columnA: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      validate: {
        is: ["[a-z]",'i'],        // will only allow letters
        max: 23,                  // only allow values <= 23
        isIn: {
          args: [['en', 'zh']],
          msg: "Must be English or Chinese"
        }
      },
      field: 'column_a'
  },
  columnB: Sequelize.STRING,
  columnC: 'MY VERY OWN COLUMN TYPE'
});

sequelize.models.modelName
```

Repare que no final existe o seguinte código: sequelize.models.modelName